# Covariant derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

> $f(T,B)$ where $T = T(t)$, $B = B(t)$ and $$f_B(T,B) = \frac{\partial}{\partial B} f(T,B)$$
>
> Now
>
> \begin{eqnarray} \nabla^\alpha \nabla_\gamma f_B &=& g^{\alpha \sigma} \nabla_\sigma \nabla_\gamma f_B\\ &=& g^{\alpha \sigma} \nabla_\alpha(\partial_\gamma f_B)\\ &=& g^{\alpha \sigma} (\partial_\alpha\partial_\gamma f_B - {\Gamma^\nu}_{\alpha\gamma} \partial_\nu f_B) \end{eqnarray}

Is that the right way to expand this expression, if $f(T, B)$ is scalar function? And if $f(T,B)$ is not scalar then how we would expand it? Here $T=T(t)$ is torsion scalar and $B=B(t)$ is boundary term

Comment: What is the context for these calculations? What result are you trying to get to?

Comment: I only want to expand this expression by using the definition of covariant derivative

Comment: is $f_B$ a scalar? If so, the covariant derivative acting on scalars is just the ordinary derivative. Also, does $f_B$ depend only on $t=x^0$ (and not on the rest of $x^\mu$) as your notation seems to suggest?

Comment: Never use an index thrice. Write $\nabla^\alpha$ as $g^{\alpha\delta}\nabla_\delta$, not $g^{\alpha\alpha}\nabla_\alpha$. You should update your calculations (preferably with [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)).

Comment: yes it is a scalar quantity and B only depends on t

Answer (score 1):

You want $\nabla^\alpha\nabla_\gamma f_B=g^{\alpha\delta}\color{blue}{\nabla_\delta\nabla_\gamma f_B}$. Let's calculate the blue part:$$\nabla_\delta\nabla_\gamma f_B=\nabla_\delta\partial_\gamma f_B=\partial_\delta\partial_\gamma f_B-\Gamma_{\delta\gamma}^\epsilon\partial_\epsilon f_B.$$